# How to remove data from native storage in ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic4, cordova-nativestorage

i'm actually trying to remove a precise data in my native storage and i try to use splice but i'm not sure that its working like this , do you have an idea ?

```
this.nativeStorage.getItem('AccepterPart').then(res => {
              for (let i of (JSON.parse(res))) {
                if (i['HISTO_N'] == this.currentNumInter) {
                  i['HISTO_Objet2'] = '106';
                  this.tabEffectuer.push(i);
                }
                var p = JSON.parse(res);
                var ind = p.findIndex(i => i['HISTO_N'] === this.currentNumInter);
                var inde = p.filter(i => i.HISTO_N !== this.currentNumInter);
                p.splice(inde);
                this.nativeStorage.setItem('AccepterPart', JSON.stringify(p));
              }
              this.nativeStorage.setItem('EffectuerPart', JSON.stringify(this.tabEffectuer));
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

To clear storage completely , use

```
this.nativeStorage.clear();
```

To remove a field, use

```
 this.nativeStorage.remove('AccepterPart');
```

Comment: Note, I Suggest to use Localstorage instead of Ionic Native storage. Since Localstorage  is more faster than Ionic Nativestorage.